# how to remove directory in linux which is not empty

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove a non-empty directory in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284552/how-to-remove-a-non-empty-directory-in-c)

I have the directory name. i am trying **remove(dir_name)**, but as the directory is not empty its returning false.

How can i delete the directory. Is there any `built-in function` which i can call??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a non-empty directory in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284552/how-to-remove-a-non-empty-directory-in-c) and [How do I remove a directory that is not empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653771/how-do-i-remove-a-directory-that-is-not-empty)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To recursively remove a directory and all it's contents, use the following command in a terminal:

```
rm -rf /path/to/dir
```

*Edit*: Seems I was confused by your mention of `built-in function`, I was assuming a function "built into" linux. Obviously this is not C++ code. If that's what you want, see the question linked to in Fred Larson's comment to your original question.

Comment: Wrap it in a system("");  And it *might* work :)